# Do I need schema registry if my team will provide jar library with model?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, confluent-schema-registry

We are starting new project with `Kafka` and `Protocol Buffers` as a data format.

It looks like Serializer/Deserializer provided by `Confluent` is assuming usage of `Schema-Registy`, but since my team is going to publish new jar every time a model changes is there any reason to use the registry at all?

I've read multiple articles and sources, but still can't really understand why use schema registry if you have model already. Is it the case when you don't get the jar with classes or any other use-case? Would be great to have some example of this in practice.

Comment: Schema registry acts a serving layer for your metadata. Schema registry is helpful if there is need of evolving schema, could be defined per topic.

As a simple example: Producer produce message in a format(avro, protobuf etc) few month later if the schema needs to change then the consumer needs to adapt to it(else pipeline will break). With schema registry in place we can enforce tighter control what message gets produced(having required fields and so on) and consumer can consume those message without causing issues with the pipeline.

Comment: Usually if the team producing and consuming the message from the topics are small(and same) and if the requirement for the evolving schema might come anytime soon; then you can certainly start of without schema registry. 

I would bucket this in "Very good to have", but "Not must have".
If you are looking for any open source schema registry: https://www.apicur.io/registry/ this could spawned as a k8 service which both the producing+consuming application can leverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you have model classes, you may need schema registry. It is more to have a schema evolution, so that no schema change would break existing consumer/producer.

Also a suggestion, irrespective of you use schema registry, I would suggest to use schema(json/avro/protbuf) in the producers and consumers to generate model classes other than adding as a lib. You can get the schema and include a plugin in your build step (maven/gradle) to generate those classes. Always keep a schema as the source of truth for all the discussions even if you are using schema registry or not in Kafka env.

Another big advantage of schema registry is it will reduce the size of the payload over wire and Kafka broker logs. No need to send the entire schema + body, we just send the schema Id + body, it will be decrypted in consumer. This will improve performance.

From an operational point of view, schema registry can act as a single source of truth for schema. Down side is that you have one more component that you need to take care of.

So it depends on your business requirement, you need to make a call based on the plus and minus. But do include only schema in code to generate the model classes on build than committing in source repo/ depending on other team for it.

Please check https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/index.html
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/avro.html